# Change separator of WM_CONCAT function of Oracle 11gR2

Tags: sql, oracle, function, oracle11g

Normally, WM_CONCAT is an aggregate function that return values from table separated by comma like here.

Suppose I have a table `foo` like this:

```
col_id     | col_text


111        | This

111        | is

111        | a

111        | test.
```

If I use this query:

```
SELECT CAST(WM_CONCAT(col_text) AS VARCHAR2(100)), col_id FROM foo
```

the result would be

```
This, is, a, test.
```

Is it possible to change the separator(`','`) to other characters like `'.'` or `'|'` of the `WM_CONCAT()` function?

Or create a user defined function that can be executed like `WM_CONCAT()`?

Comment: If you're on 11gR2 then you should use [`listagg`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions089.htm) instead. If not there are various articles about how to write your own version - like [this often-linked one](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques.php) - but you need to specify which version you're running.

Comment: 11gR2? How to determine if I am using 11gR2? When I run `SELECT *
FROM V$VERSION;` I got this: `Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production`.

Comment: The `11.2` part of the version string means you have 11g Release 2, so you will have `listagg` available. (The base release was `11.2.0.1` so you have patches applied on top of that). You could also just try to use it of course *8-)

Comment: But I have another problem. I can't just try it because of the query I created earlier. Let me update my question.

Comment: Can't you just run @peterm's version instead? In your embedded version, just replace `CAST (WM_CONCAT (C.CUST_NAME) AS VARCHAR2 (1500))` with `LISTAGG(C.CUST_NAME, '|') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY C.CUST_NAME)`. You can `cast` or `substr` that if you really need to but it probably isn't necessary.

Comment: Please check my update.=) Sorry I don't post it earlier.

Comment: I got it now. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You might want to use  [`LISTAGG`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm).

```
SELECT col_id, 
       LISTAGG(col_text, '|') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY col_text) text
  FROM table1
 GROUP BY col_id
```

Output:

```
| COL_ID |            TEXT |
----------------------------
|    111 | This|a|is|test. |
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/946ac/5)**

**UPDATE** If you need to get distinct text values in a list

```
SELECT col_id, 
       LISTAGG(col_text, '|')
         WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY col_text) text
  FROM 
(
  SELECT DISTINCT col_id, col_text
    FROM table1
)
 GROUP BY col_id
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/11ef4/2)**

Comment: I got it now. Thanks a lot @peterm.

Comment: I have another problem. How can I select distinct `TEXT`?

Comment: If I can upvote this answer again, I will upvote this. But I can't.:) Thank you again.

Comment: Hey :) it seems to be exactly what I need but it doesn't work for me: `SQL Error [904] [42000]: ORA-00904: "LISTAGG": invalid identifier`

Answer (score 4):

Problem with LISTAGG that it returns varchar2 and is limited to 4000 bytes

```
SELECT LISTAGG(LEVEL, CHR(10)) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY NULL)
  FROM Dual
CONNECT BY LEVEL < 2000

ORA-01489 Result of string concat is too large
```

I've found one workaround, but it looks ugly and is mutch slower

```
SELECT EXTRACT(XMLTYPE('<doc>' || XMLAGG(XMLTYPE('<ln>' || LEVEL || CHR(10) || '</ln>')).GetClobVal() || '</doc>'), '/doc/ln/text()').GetClobVal()
  FROM Dual
CONNECT BY LEVEL < 2000
```

Answer (score 4):

> Is it possible to change the separator(',') to other characters like '.' or '|' of the WM_CONCAT() function?

Do not use `WM_CONCAT` since it is an **undocumented feature** and it has been **removed** from the latest **12c version**. Any application which has had been relying on `wm_concat` function will not work once upgraded to `12c`. See [**Why not use WM_CONCAT function in Oracle?**](http://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2015/04/29/why-not-use-wm_concat-function-in-oracle/)

```
SQL> select banner from v$version where rownum = 1;

BANNER
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.1.0 - 64bit Production

SQL> SELECT object_name
  2  FROM dba_objects
  3  WHERE owner='WMSYS'
  4  AND object_name LIKE 'WM\_%' ESCAPE '\';

OBJECT_NAME
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
WM_REPLICATION_INFO
WM_RDIFF
WM_PERIOD
WM_PERIOD
WM_OVERLAPS
WM_MEETS
WM_LESSTHAN
WM_LDIFF
WM_INTERSECTION
WM_INSTALLATION
WM_GREATERTHAN
WM_EVENTS_INFO
WM_ERROR
WM_ERROR
WM_EQUALS
WM_DDL_UTIL
WM_DDL_UTIL
WM_CONTAINS
WM_COMPRESS_BATCH_SIZES
WM_COMPRESSIBLE_TABLES

20 rows selected.
```

You will receive an “**invalid identifier**” error:

```
SQL> SELECT banner FROM v$version;

BANNER
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 12.1.0.1.0 - Production
CORE    12.1.0.1.0      Production
TNS for 64-bit Windows: Version 12.1.0.1.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 12.1.0.1.0 - Production

SQL> SELECT deptno, wm_concat(ename) FROM emp;
SELECT deptno, wm_concat(ename) FROM emp
               *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00904: "WM_CONCAT": invalid identifier
```

Therefore, there is no point relying on an **undocumented feature** which is no more made available in latest versions.

There are various **[string aggregation techniques](https://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2015/10/12/oracle-string-aggregation-techniques/)**:

- **LISTAGG** in 11gR2 and up

For example,

```
SELECT deptno, LISTAGG(ename, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ename) AS employees
FROM   emp
GROUP BY deptno;

    DEPTNO EMPLOYEES
---------- --------------------------------------------------
        10 CLARK,KING,MILLER
        20 ADAMS,FORD,JONES,SCOTT,SMITH
        30 ALLEN,BLAKE,JAMES,MARTIN,TURNER,WARD

3 rows selected.
```

- **ROW_NUMBER()** and **SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH** functions in 9i and up

For example,

```
SELECT deptno,
       LTRIM(MAX(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(ename,','))
       KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY curr),',') AS employees
FROM   (SELECT deptno,
               ename,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY deptno ORDER BY ename) AS curr,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY deptno ORDER BY ename) -1 AS prev
        FROM   emp)
GROUP BY deptno
CONNECT BY prev = PRIOR curr AND deptno = PRIOR deptno
START WITH curr = 1;

    DEPTNO EMPLOYEES
---------- --------------------------------------------------
        10 CLARK,KING,MILLER
        20 ADAMS,FORD,JONES,SCOTT,SMITH
        30 ALLEN,BLAKE,JAMES,MARTIN,TURNER,WARD

3 rows selected.
```

- User-defined aggregate function **STRAGG** described in [AskTom](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:2196162600402).
- **COLLECT** function in 10g and up

A few good examples by Tim Hall [here](http://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques.php).

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me on an ORACLE 10.2.0.5.0 database:

```
SELECT col_id, replace(wm_concat(col_text), ',', ' ') AS sentence
  FROM foo
 GROUP BY col_id;
```

Comment: @ChristianMark Hi, do you mind elaborate more on how is the impact on performance?