# Convert WM_CONCAT to Listagg

Tags: sql, oracle, listagg, wm-concat

My DBA is upgrading my oracle db from v10 to v12.
I have some old SP's that uses `wm_concat` and I need to change it to `listagg`.
The problematic code is this:

```
Select  registration_id,package_set_id,
        REPLACE(REPLACE(WM_CONCAT(REPLACE( (case when ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by product_id,product_detail_set_id,registration_id,product_family_id,application_id,package_Set_id,
               legal_status order by packset_country)=1 then legal_status else null end), ',' , '#')) OVER (PARTITION BY PRODUCT_ID,  PRODUCT_DETAIL_SET_ID,
               REGISTRATION_ID  ,PRODUCT_FAMILY_ID,APPLICATION_ID,PACKAGE_SET_ID   ORDER BY Packset_country  ), ',' , ' | '), '#', ',') as legal_status,

        (REPLACE(REPLACE(WM_CONCAT(REPLACE(ev_code, ',' , '#')) OVER (PARTITION BY PRODUCT_ID,  PRODUCT_DETAIL_SET_ID,
               REGISTRATION_ID  ,PRODUCT_FAMILY_ID,APPLICATION_ID,PACKAGE_SET_ID   ORDER BY ev_code  ), ',' , ' | '), '#', ',')) EV_CODES,

         min(marketed_date) over (PARTITION BY PRODUCT_ID,  PRODUCT_DETAIL_SET_ID,REGISTRATION_ID  ,PRODUCT_FAMILY_ID,APPLICATION_ID,PACKAGE_SET_ID) as marketed_date,

         (REPLACE(REPLACE(WM_CONCAT(REPLACE(Packset_country, ',' , '#')) OVER (PARTITION BY PRODUCT_ID,  PRODUCT_DETAIL_SET_ID, REGISTRATION_ID ,PRODUCT_FAMILY_ID,
                APPLICATION_ID,PACKAGE_SET_ID   ORDER BY Packset_country, reg_packset_country_id ), ',' , ' | '), '#', ',')) REGISTRATION_PACKSET_COUNTRIES,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PRODUCT_ID,  PRODUCT_DETAIL_SET_ID,REGISTRATION_ID  ,PRODUCT_FAMILY_ID,APPLICATION_ID,PACKAGE_SET_ID  
                ORDER BY Packset_country desc ,reg_packset_country_id)  ROW_NUM,     
         REPLACE(REPLACE(WM_CONCAT(REPLACE( (case when currently_marketed_in_country='Y' then packset_country end), ',' , '#')) OVER (PARTITION BY PRODUCT_ID,  PRODUCT_DETAIL_SET_ID,
                REGISTRATION_ID  ,PRODUCT_FAMILY_ID,APPLICATION_ID,PACKAGE_SET_ID  ORDER BY packset_country ,currently_marketed_in_country,reg_packset_country_id ), ',' , ' | '), '#', ',') as CURRENTLY_MARKETED_COUNTRIES
from radw_dwh.dw202_fact_reg_pack_countries
```

The expected result is:[image]

I tried to change it but there is a problem when I'm trying to use "ROW_NUMBER()" in side "LISTAGG".

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 5):

The basic syntax of **LISTAGG** is:

```
LISTAGG(col_name_to_be_aggregated, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY col)
```

In your case, since you have a sub-query as result set to `WM_CONCAT`, you could put the same sub-query in place of `col_name_to_be_aggregated` in **LISTAGG**.

I think you can also get rid of all the **REPLACE** functions, since, LISTAGG can accept the **delimiter** of your choice.

Try,

```
LISTAGG
(
  CASE
  WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY product_id,
                                       product_detail_set_id,
                                       registration_id,
                                       product_family_id,
                                       application_id,
                                       package_Set_id, 
                                       legal_status 
                                       order by packset_country)=1 THEN
    legal_status
  ELSE
    NULL
  END), ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY required_col)
```

---

Also, I would like to explain why you need to move to LISTAGG in 12c. Since t has been removed from the latest 12c version. Therefore, any application which has had been relying on WM_CONCAT function will not work once upgraded to 12c. Read [**Why not use WM_CONCAT function in Oracle?**](http://lalitkumarb.com/2015/04/29/why-not-use-wm_concat-function-in-oracle/)

For pre-11g Release 2, you can't use LISTAGG. There are many string aggregation techniques, have a look at my answer [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30272927/3989608).

More details about [**Oracle String Aggregation Techniques**](http://lalitkumarb.com/2015/10/12/oracle-string-aggregation-techniques/)

Comment: Its still throwing an exception: ORA-30483

Comment: @AlanMil I can't help with something I can't see. Also, without the create and insert statements, it is impossible to help further. Nobody can run your code, since nobody has the tables and the data. You should provide a test case, i.e. create table statements and insert statements as sample data.

Comment: create table DW202_FACT_REG_PACK_COUNTRIES
(
  reg_packset_country_id         NUMBER(10),
  product_family_id              NUMBER(10),
  application_id                 NUMBER(10),
  packset_country                VARCHAR2(500),
  product_id                     NUMBER(10),
  product_detail_set_id          NUMBER(10),
  registration_id                NUMBER(10),
  package_set_id                 NUMBER(10),
  legal_status                   VARCHAR2(500)
);

Comment: INSERT INTO radw_dwh.dw202_fact_reg_pack_countries
(reg_packset_country_id, product_family_id, application_id,packset_country,product_id,product_detail_set_id,registration_id, package_set_id,legal_status)
VALUES
(10267249,1004887, 1004969,'Denmark',3763839,4014072,25351829, 9614690,'')
VALUES
(10366981,1211763, 1221071,'Lithuania',3762066,4026448,25352879, 9379580,'')
VALUES
(11379332,515880, 724392,'Germany',3755922,4072209,4909517, 10695769,'Prescription-Only')
VALUES
(23733439,3367178, 10512281,'Argentina',3766320,23442608,10512310, 23443326,'Prescription-Only');

Comment: @AlanMil Ok good. Now, post the expected output. Please edit your question and add it.

Comment: `SELECT registration_id,
  package_set_id,
  LISTAGG (
  ( SELECT DISTINCT
    CASE
      WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY product_id, product_detail_set_id, registration_id, product_family_id, application_id, package_Set_id, legal_status order by packset_country)=1
      THEN legal_status
    END legal_status
  FROM dw202_fact_reg_pack_countries
  WHERE legal_status IS NOT NULL
  ) , ',') WITHIN GROUP (
ORDER BY packset_country) EV_CODES
FROM dw202_fact_reg_pack_countries
GROUP BY registration_id,
  package_set_id;`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92857/discussion-between-alan-mil-and-lalit-kumar-b).

Answer (score 1):

## Motivation for the following approach

We had several problems with `wm_concat` (known bugs) or `wm_concat`-to-`list_agg`-conversion-for-12c-use.

(Not to mention the nice compact/declarative usage using `wm_concat` in many scenarios where other solutions may be quite complicated to read.)

(Sometimes having to use `xmlagg` because of `> 4000 chars`/`clob` problems or `regexp_replace` workarounds for the `wm_concat( distinct ... )` emulation), e.g. [like here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39325808/1915920).

## Strategy

So finally in my opinion a **rather nice strategy** (which may differ depending on your environment/needs/strategy) is, to

1. create two functions

   - **`create function  wm_concat_32767(...`** (working on `varchar(32767)` which is possible since *Oracle 12c*) and

     - depending on [`MAX_STRING_SIZE`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-D424D23B-0933-425F-BC69-9C0E6724693C.htm#REFRN10321) of your db you may want to adopt this to "`4000`" or others
   - **`create function  wm_concat_clob(...`** in your db in the sys-schema first.
   - They should be based on code like provided by [the answer from *Dart XKey*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33228581/1915920) (maybe copied from [*asktom/Tom Kyte*](https://web.archive.org/web/20150906040401/https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:2196162600402))
2. **`create public synonym  wm_concat  for  sys.wm_concat_32767`**

   - (I would generally let the `wm_concat` point to the likely faster `wm_concat_32767` rather than `wm_concat_clob`)
   - this allows the easy reuse/migration of existing `wm_concat(varchar(4000))` based *< 11.2g* code/usage
   - one might already know the name of the function and thus easy to get use to
   - (the problem that online documentation about it may be misleading is what I could live with since the benefits would outweight the disadvantages for me in general)
   - it will even allow the use of `wm_concat( distinct ... )` queries with compact declarative syntax

     - as opposed to the `listagg`/`xmlagg`/`regexp_replace`-based workarounds mentioned above
3. **`create public synonym  wm_concat_clob  for  sys.wm_concat_clob`**
4. give **proper public execution rights** to the `wm_concat_*`functions

## Code

So finally the adopted code we use (maybe I'll update everything mentioned above over time):

`wm_concat_32767(...)` creation:

- depending on [`MAX_STRING_SIZE`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-D424D23B-0933-425F-BC69-9C0E6724693C.htm#REFRN10321) of your db you may want to adopt this to "`4000`" or other values

_

```
create or replace type  string_agg_type  as object ( 
  total varchar2(32767), 
  static function ODCIAggregateInitialize(sctx IN OUT string_agg_type ) return number,
  member function ODCIAggregateIterate(self IN OUT string_agg_type , value IN varchar2 ) return number, 
  member function ODCIAggregateTerminate(self IN string_agg_type, returnValue OUT varchar2, flags IN number) return number,
  member function ODCIAggregateMerge(self IN OUT string_agg_type, ctx2 IN string_agg_type) return number 
); 
/ 
create or replace type body  string_agg_type  is static function odciaggregateinitialize(sctx IN OUT string_agg_type) return number is begin sctx := string_agg_type(null); return odciconst.success; end; 
  member function odciaggregateiterate(self IN OUT string_agg_type, value IN varchar2) return number is begin self.total := self.total || ',' || value; return odciconst.success; end; 
  member function odciaggregateterminate(self IN string_agg_type, returnvalue OUT varchar2, flags IN number) return number is begin returnvalue := ltrim(self.total, ','); return odciconst.success; end; 
  member function odciaggregatemerge(self IN OUT string_agg_type, ctx2 IN string_agg_type) return number is begin self.total := self.total || ctx2.total; return odciconst.success; end; 
end;
/ 
CREATE or replace FUNCTION  wm_concat_32767(input varchar2) RETURN varchar2 PARALLEL_ENABLE AGGREGATE USING string_agg_type; 
/
```

`wm_concat_clob(...)` creation based on [this code from Michel Cadot](http://www.dba-village.com/village/dvp_forum.OpenThread?ThreadIdA=78622):

```
create or replace type  stragg_type4  as object (
  result CLOB,
  static function ODCIAggregateInitialize (sctx IN OUT stragg_type4) return number,
  member function ODCIAggregateIterate (self IN OUT stragg_type4, value IN varchar2) return number,
  member function ODCIAggregateTerminate (self IN stragg_type4, returnValue OUT CLOB, flags IN number) return number,
  member function ODCIAggregateMerge (self IN OUT stragg_type4, ctx2 IN stragg_type4) return number
);
/

create or replace type body  stragg_type4  is

  static function ODCIAggregateInitialize (sctx IN OUT stragg_type4) return number is begin
    sctx := stragg_type4 (null);
    dbms_lob.createtemporary (lob_loc => sctx.result, cache   => TRUE, dur => dbms_lob.call);
    return ODCIConst.Success;
  end;

  member function ODCIAggregateIterate (self IN OUT stragg_type4, value IN varchar2) return number is begin
    self.result := self.result || ',' || value;
    return ODCIConst.Success;
  end;

  member function ODCIAggregateTerminate (self IN stragg_type4, returnValue OUT CLOB, flags IN number) return number is begin
    returnValue := ltrim (self.result, ',');
    return ODCIConst.Success;
  end;

  member function ODCIAggregateMerge (self IN OUT stragg_type4, ctx2 IN stragg_type4) return number is begin
    self.result := self.result || ctx2.result;
    return ODCIConst.Success;
  end;

end;
/

sho err

CREATE or replace FUNCTION wm_concat_clob(input varchar2) RETURN CLOB PARALLEL_ENABLE AGGREGATE USING stragg_type4;
/
```

Comment: Underrated answer. This was the only one that let me replace my old WM_CONCAT.

Answer (score 0):

As example in code odciaggregate interface in code:

```
    create or replace type string_agg_type as object ( total varchar2(4000), 
static function ODCIAggregateInitialize(sctx IN OUT string_agg_type ) return number,
 member function ODCIAggregateIterate(self IN OUT string_agg_type , value IN varchar2 ) return number, 
member function ODCIAggregateTerminate(self IN string_agg_type, returnValue OUT varchar2, flags IN number) return number,
 member function ODCIAggregateMerge(self IN OUT string_agg_type, ctx2 IN string_agg_type) return number ); 
/ 
create or replace type body string_agg_type is static function odciaggregateinitialize(sctx IN OUT string_agg_type) return number is begin sctx := string_agg_type(null); return odciconst.success; end; 
member function odciaggregateiterate(self IN OUT string_agg_type, value IN varchar2) return number is begin self.total := self.total || ',' || value; return odciconst.success; end; 
member function odciaggregateterminate(self IN string_agg_type, returnvalue OUT varchar2, flags IN number) return number is begin returnvalue := ltrim(self.total, ','); return odciconst.success; end; 
member function odciaggregatemerge(self IN OUT string_agg_type, ctx2 IN string_agg_type) return number is begin self.total := self.total || ctx2.total; return odciconst.success; end; 
end;
/ 
CREATE or replace FUNCTION stragg(input varchar2) RETURN varchar2 PARALLEL_ENABLE AGGREGATE USING string_agg_type; 
/


with t as ( select 'a1' val from dual union all select 'b2' val from dual ) select stragg(val) as val from t; val --------------------------- a1,b2
```