# Define "WM_CONCAT(col)" as "LISTAGG(col, ',')" for Oracle Migration

Tags: oracle, database-migration, listagg, wm-concat

We are in the process of migrating from Oracle 10g to 18c for our environment databases.  To complicate things, not all environments are planned to be migrated at once and so the app must support both for a time.  One of the incompatibilities uncovered is that `WM_Concat` is supported in 10g but not 18c, and `ListAgg` (the new equivalent function) is supported in 18c but not 10g.  Thus, I'm looking for an implementation that will work in both database versions for the time being.

My thought is that `wm_concat(myColumn)` in 10g is equivalent to `listagg(myColumn, ',')` in 18c, so I'd like to define `wm_concat(myColumn)` to be a function in the new 18c databases that passes-through to `listagg(myColumn, ',')` behind the scenes and returns the result.  That way, the app can safely continue using `wm_concat` as normal on both the 10g and 18c databases until all environments are on 18c, after which the app can be swapped to use `listagg` and the temporary custom `wm_concat` function can be removed from the 18c databases, completing the migration.

To summarize, what is the proper way to define `wm_concat` so that `wm_concat(myColumn)` will behave exactly the same as `listagg(myColumn, ',')` in a query?

Comment: Almost a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33212899/convert-wm-concat-to-listagg?rq=1 but that one is about migrating from `WM_CONCAT` to `LISTAGG`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[TL;DR] You can't implement a custom version of `WM_CONCAT` in Oracle 18c to behave exactly the same as `LISTAGG` but you can get close with a user-defined aggregation function.

---

[`LISTAGG` has the syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030):

> [image: LISTAGG function]

`WM_CONCAT` has the syntax:

> `WM_CONCAT( expr )`

You can see that `WM_CONCAT` is lacking the ability to specify a delimiter or an `ORDER BY` clause.

If you want to redefine `WM_CONCAT` in later versions then you will probably end up using a user-defined aggregation function:

**User-Defined Object**:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE t_string_agg AS OBJECT
(
  g_string  VARCHAR2(32767),

  STATIC FUNCTION ODCIAggregateInitialize(
    sctx  IN OUT  t_string_agg
  ) RETURN NUMBER,

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateIterate(
    self   IN OUT  t_string_agg,
    value  IN      VARCHAR2
  ) RETURN NUMBER,

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateTerminate(
    self         IN   t_string_agg,
    returnValue  OUT  VARCHAR2,
    flags        IN   NUMBER
  ) RETURN NUMBER,

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateMerge(
    self  IN OUT  t_string_agg,
    ctx2  IN      t_string_agg
  ) RETURN NUMBER
);
/
```

**User-Defined Object Body**:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY t_string_agg IS
  STATIC FUNCTION ODCIAggregateInitialize(
    sctx  IN OUT  t_string_agg
  ) RETURN NUMBER
  IS
  BEGIN
    sctx := t_string_agg(NULL);
    RETURN ODCIConst.Success;
  END;

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateIterate(
    self   IN OUT  t_string_agg,
    value  IN      VARCHAR2
  ) RETURN NUMBER
  IS
  BEGIN
    SELF.g_string := self.g_string || ',' || value;
    RETURN ODCIConst.Success;
  END;

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateTerminate(
    self         IN   t_string_agg,
    returnValue  OUT  VARCHAR2,
    flags        IN   NUMBER
  ) RETURN NUMBER
  IS
  BEGIN
    returnValue := SUBSTR( SELF.g_string, 2 );
    RETURN ODCIConst.Success;
  END;

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateMerge(
    self  IN OUT  t_string_agg,
    ctx2  IN      t_string_agg
  ) RETURN NUMBER
  IS
  BEGIN
    SELF.g_string := SELF.g_string || ctx2.g_string;
    RETURN ODCIConst.Success;
  END;
END;
/
```

**User-Defined Aggregation Function**:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION wm_concat (p_input VARCHAR2)
RETURN VARCHAR2
PARALLEL_ENABLE AGGREGATE USING t_string_agg;
/
```

**Test Data**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test_data ( id, value ) AS
  SELECT 1, 'C' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 'A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 'B' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'D' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'E' FROM DUAL;
```

**Test Query**:

```sql
SELECT id,
       wm_concat( value ) AS wm_concat,
       LISTAGG( value, ',' ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY ROWNUM ) AS listagg
FROM   test_data
GROUP BY id;
```

**Output**:

> ```
> ID | WM_CONCAT | LISTAGG
> -: | :-------- | :------
>  1 | C,B,A     | C,A,B  
>  2 | D,E       | D,E
> ```

As you can see the ordering of the output is different; so you can get close but not an exact match.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=51340724f2e86defd2056e6fee2cd2bd)*

---

**Update**:

If we go for an inefficient aggregation function that stores all the values in a collection and then calls `LISTAGG` then we can get closer:

```sql
CREATE TYPE stringlist IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(4000);

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE t_string_agg AS OBJECT
(
  strings stringlist,

  STATIC FUNCTION ODCIAggregateInitialize(
    sctx  IN OUT  t_string_agg
  ) RETURN NUMBER,

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateIterate(
    self   IN OUT  t_string_agg,
    value  IN      VARCHAR2
  ) RETURN NUMBER,

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateTerminate(
    self         IN   t_string_agg,
    returnValue  OUT  VARCHAR2,
    flags        IN   NUMBER
  ) RETURN NUMBER,

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateMerge(
    self  IN OUT  t_string_agg,
    ctx2  IN      t_string_agg
  ) RETURN NUMBER
);
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY t_string_agg IS
  STATIC FUNCTION ODCIAggregateInitialize(
    sctx  IN OUT  t_string_agg
  ) RETURN NUMBER
  IS
  BEGIN
    sctx := t_string_agg( stringlist() );
    RETURN ODCIConst.Success;
  END;

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateIterate(
    self   IN OUT  t_string_agg,
    value  IN      VARCHAR2
  ) RETURN NUMBER
  IS
  BEGIN
    SELF.strings.EXTEND;
    SELF.strings( SELF.strings.COUNT ) := value;
    RETURN ODCIConst.Success;
  END;

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateTerminate(
    self         IN   t_string_agg,
    returnValue  OUT  VARCHAR2,
    flags        IN   NUMBER
  ) RETURN NUMBER
  IS
  BEGIN
    SELECT LISTAGG( column_value, ',' ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY column_value )
    INTO   returnValue
    FROM   TABLE( SELF.strings );
    RETURN ODCIConst.Success;
  END;

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateMerge(
    self  IN OUT  t_string_agg,
    ctx2  IN      t_string_agg
  ) RETURN NUMBER
  IS
  BEGIN
    SELF.strings := SELF.strings MULTISET UNION ALL ctx2.strings;
    RETURN ODCIConst.Success;
  END;
END;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION wm_concat (p_input VARCHAR2)
RETURN VARCHAR2
PARALLEL_ENABLE AGGREGATE USING t_string_agg;
/
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT id,
       wm_concat( value ) AS wm_concat,
       LISTAGG( value, ',' ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY value ) AS listagg
FROM   test_data
GROUP BY id;
```

outputs:

> ```
> ID | WM_CONCAT | LISTAGG
> -: | :-------- | :------
>  1 | A,B,C     | A,B,C  
>  2 | D,E       | D,E
> ```

It will give the same output as `LISTAGG` if (and only if) you want to sort the values alphabetically; you can't specify a different ordering. It also requires a context switch from PL/SQL to SQL to preform the aggregation in the final step so it is likely to be slower than a pure PL/SQL aggregation function and it will keep the collection in memory and keep extending it so there will be additional overheads as the collection grows (or gets merged in parallel systems) that will slow it further.

So it's still not `LISTAGG` but its about as close as you can get if you are willing to put up with issues around performance.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=57fdd3380ee13545ce1a4adb64bd71a0)*