# Change WM_CONCAT function to LISTAGG

Tags: sql, oracle, listagg

I used `WM_CONCAT` in my sql query. The database has been updated to version 12c and `WM_CONCAT` doesn`t work.

Query had value:

```
Select r.product_id, count (1) how_many, wm_concat (distinct r.number) numbers From ...
```

How to transform it into `LISTAGG` functions. I try this, but it doesn`t work :

```
Select r.product_id, count(1) how_many, LISTAGG(r.number, ',') WITHIN GROUP (order by r.number) numbers From ...
```

Comment: "it doesn`t work" is not a problem description. Why doesn't it work? Do you get an error (if so, what's the message), or unexpected results, or what?

Comment: @HoneyBadger ORA-00937: not a single-group group function

Comment: @xampo Please don't add additional (crucial) information in a comment. [Edit] your question instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should add Group by in your query

```
with tab as(
  select '10' as num, 'A' as product from dual union all
  select '10' as num, 'B' as product from dual union all
  select '10' as num, 'C' as product from dual union all
  select '10' as num, 'D' as product from dual union all
  select '20' as num, 'A' as product from dual union all
  select '20' as num, 'B' as product from dual union all
  select '30' as num, 'A' as product from dual
)

select  product
, count (1) how_many
, LISTAGG(num, ',') WITHIN GROUP (order by num) 
from tab
group by product
```

but you have to be careful, because by using `listagg` you can only concatenate strings up to 4K. There are also other string aggregation techniques, have a look at  the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16786951/change-separator-of-wm-concat-function-of-oracle-11gr2/30272927#30272927).

> ```
> PRODUCT | HOW_MANY | LISTAGG(NUM,',')WITHINGROUP(ORDERBYNUM)
> :------ | -------: | :--------------------------------------
> A       |        3 | 10,20,30                               
> B       |        2 | 10,20                                  
> C       |        1 | 10                                     
> D       |        1 | 10
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ce6a0d73c4aa660d395414e636c30593)*

Comment: Starting with Oracle 12.2, LISTAGG can handle overflows gracefully - see https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/listagg-function-enhancements-12cr2#handling-overflow-errors