# SQL: removing duplicate rows where column values may be permutated

Tags: sql, oracle, duplicates, rows

Imagine a table with four columns: A,B,C and D.
If I have multiple rows where the 4 values are the same (but they might be located in different columns), how do I keep only 1 of these rows and remove the others ? (It does not matter which one stays)

Example:

```
A  B  C  D
----------
1  2  2  3 
3  2  1  2
2  1  2  3
2  2  1  3
1  8  8  8
8  1  8  8
```

Where the result should be:

```
A  B  C  D
----------
1  2  2  3 
8  1  8  8
```

Is this problem possible **without** using: scalar subqueries, union / union all

**Allowed**: joins, CTE's, rank / dense_rank / row_number / count, case expressions

Comment: I guess you could use some kind of checksum to combine all the columns into one, then just check that one column for duplicates.

Comment: what about creating a function?

Comment: Are you asking to do your homework?

Comment: No, it is for school though. It was (part of) a previous exam question. I usually never ask anything online schoolrelated unless it just bugs me that I didn't find the answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I'll do this with the help of a function that sorts characters in a given string. 
So first let's create a function

```
create or replace function sortString(str in Varchar2) return varchar2 is
res  varchar2(500);
begin 
SELECT MIN(permutations) into res
FROM (SELECT REPLACE (SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH (n, ','), ',') permutations
    FROM (SELECT LEVEL l, SUBSTR (str, LEVEL, 1) n
        FROM DUAL
        CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH (str)) yourtable
    CONNECT BY NOCYCLE l != PRIOR l)
WHERE LENGTH (permutations) = LENGTH (str);
return res;
end;
```

and after that

```
DELETE FROM 
   table_name A
WHERE 
  a.rowid > 
   ANY (
     SELECT 
        B.rowid
     FROM 
        table_name B
     WHERE 
        sortString(A.col1 ||A.col2 || A.col3 ||A.col4)=sortString(B.col1 || B.col2 || B.col3 || B.col4)
        );
```

some references: [sortString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835634/sort-chars-in-varchar2-alphabetically) (1) , [delete duplicates](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_delete_duplicate_table_rows.htm) (2)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of function with hierarchical query proposed by @Plirkee you could unpivot data (subquery `T1`), sort them using proper ordering in function `list_agg()` (subquery `T2`) in order to find rows having minimum `rowid` for each unique list, delete rest of rows:

```
delete from t where rowid not in (
  with t1 as (select rd, col, val
                from (select rowid rd, a, b, c, d from t) 
                unpivot (val for (col) in ("A", "B", "C", "D"))),
       t2 as (select rd, 
                     listagg(val, '-') within group (order by val) 
                       over (partition by rd) as list 
                from t1)
  select min(rd) from t2 group by list )
```

This worked for my test data. There is no problem if columns A, B, C, D are positive numbers. Something strange could happen if they were negative or strings, especially containing '-'. In this case you should use some other separator for `listagg()`.