# How to arrange/sort string in Oracle SQL - 11g

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11gr2

I have a string an string "ADBDkK" and I need to sort it as "ABDDKk", like Arrays.sort() in java. I know it can be done by using PL/SQL but I need of this in Oracle SQL statement.

Input:

```
ADBDkK
ZXYABC
```

Output:

```
ABDDKk
ABCXYZ
```

Comment: maybe this could help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835634/sort-chars-in-varchar2-alphabetically

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/89577/5)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE test ( value ) AS
SELECT 'ADBDkK' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ZXYABC' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
WITH chars ( id, value, ch, lvl ) AS (
  SELECT ROWNUM, value, SUBSTR( value, 1, 1 ), 1
  FROM   test
UNION ALL
  SELECT id, value, SUBSTR( value, lvl+1, 1 ), lvl+1
  FROM   chars
  WHERE  lvl < LENGTH( value )
)
SELECT LISTAGG( ch ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY ch ) AS value
FROM   chars
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY id
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/89577/5/0)**:

```
|  VALUE |
|--------|
| ABDDKk |
| ABCXYZ |
```

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT LISTAGG( COLUMN_VALUE )
         WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY COLUMN_VALUE ) AS value
FROM   (
  SELECT value,
         ROWNUM AS id
  FROM test
) t
CROSS JOIN
TABLE(
  CAST(
    MULTISET(
      SELECT SUBSTR( t.value, LEVEL, 1 )
      FROM   DUAL
      CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH( t.value )
    )
    AS SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST
  )
) c
GROUP BY t.id
ORDER BY t.id
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/89577/5/1)**:

```
|  VALUE |
|--------|
| ABDDKk |
| ABCXYZ |
```

Comment: It works fine for me, Is there any sort way to do the same thing?

Comment: What do you mean? This is sorting it.

Comment: Write a PL/SQL function to perform the sort - but you said you didn't want that in the question.

Comment: Yes, that I don't want. Anyway, it's working for me. Thanks @MT

Answer (score 1):

For a **single** string:

```
select listagg(regexp_substr('ADBDkK', '\w', 1 ,level),'') 
   within group (order by 1) from dual
connect by regexp_substr('ADBDkK', '\w', 1 ,level) is not null;
```

A slightly different way using a `function`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sort_string(my_string IN VARCHAR2)
  RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
  ret_string VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
  SELECT LISTAGG(regexp_substr(my_string, '\w', 1, level), '') WITHIN
   GROUP(
   ORDER BY 1)
    INTO ret_string
    FROM dual
  CONNECT BY regexp_substr(my_string, '\w', 1, level) IS NOT NULL;
  RETURN ret_string;
END;
```

Then from `sqlplus`:

```
SQL> select sort_string('ADBDkK') as RESULT from dual;

RESULT
------
ABDDKk

SQL> select sort_string('ZXYABC') as RESULT from dual;

RESULT
------
ABCXYZ
```

Comment: This will only work for a single string - if you try this on a table with multiple rows then the hierarchical query cannot correlate the hierarchy to a single table row and will start to generate exponentially more duplicate rows as the hierarchy deepens.

Comment: That's correct, It must be integrated in a function

Comment: You don't need a function; you can also correlate it using a `MULTISET` statement (as the 2nd query in my answer). Also, why use `REGEXP_SUBSTR` and not just `SUBSTR`?

Comment: Not saying I need a `function` this is just an *alternative* way to do it, your answer is great BTW

Answer (score -1):

```
with t1 as (
select 'London Singapur' tmp  from dual union all
select 'Singapur China'  tmp  from dual union all
select 'USA JAPAN '      tmp  from dual union all
select 'JAPAN USA'       tmp  from dual union all 
select 'Singapur London' tmp  from dual 
),
dst as ( select ROWNUM rwn,tmp,REGEXP_COUNT(tmp,'[^[:space:]]+') cnt_array  from t1 ),

rc(id, cnt_id, tmp, CNT_ARRAY, SL) AS (
   SELECT rwn id,1 cnt_id,tmp, CNT_ARRAY, regexp_substr(tmp,'[^[:space:]]+',1,1) sl FROM   dst   
      UNION ALL
    SELECT rc.id, rc.cnt_id+1 cnt_id, rc.tmp, rc.CNT_ARRAY, regexp_substr(rc.tmp,'[^[:space:]]+',1,rc.cnt_id+1) sl
    FROM   dst tr, rc 
    WHERE  tr.rwn = rc.id and rc.cnt_id+1<=tr.CNT_ARRAY
),

srt as (select  rc.*,row_number() over (partition by id order by id) nb,
                listagg(sl,' ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY sl) over(partition by id) fiel_srt
        from rc)

select * from srt where nb=1
```